# Dynamically set currency pipe in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

How can able change the angular currency pipe dynamically? I'm getting data from API and it includes currency type. I want to show it's in interpolation.

```
<td>{{ pro.CostPrice | currency: pro.Currency }}</td>
```

This is the output I'm getting if I use the above way.

> $300.00

Comment: i think you need to set <td>{{ pro.CostPrice | currency: {{pro.Currency}} }}</td> like this

Comment: Could you please provide confirm whether the `pro.Currency` value resolves to a currency code that conforms with [ISO 4217](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217) currency code, such as USD for the US dollar and EUR for the euro or not?